# ActiveRecord::Base#find returns no records in Single Table Inheritance (STI)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sti

app/models

```
class Amodel < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Bmodel < Amodel
end

class Cmodel < Bmodel  
end
```

db/migrate

```
create_table :amodels do |t|
  t.string :type
end
```

on script/console...

```
$ script/console
Loading development environment (Rails 2.3.4)
>> Cmodel.create
=> #<Cmodel id: 1, type: "Cmodel">
>> Bmodel.find(:all)
=> [#<Cmodel id: 1, type: "Cmodel">]
```

ok, but Bmodel returns no records after rebooting console like:

```
>> exit
$ script/console
Loading development environment (Rails 2.3.4)
>> Bmodel.find(:all)
=> []
```

however, it works after accessing Cmodel:

```
>> Cmodel
=> Cmodel(id: integer, type: string)
>> Bmodel.find(:all)
=> [#<Cmodel id: 1, type: "Cmodel">]
```

Amodel works like:

```
>> exit
$ script/console
Loading development environment (Rails 2.3.4)
>> Amodel.find(:all)
=> [#<Cmodel id: 1, type: "Cmodel">]
```

Does anyone know why it works like this?

Rails: 2.3.4
Ruby: 1.8.7
OS: Ubuntu 9.0.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the way ActiveRecord STI is built. When a class is loaded, it registers with it's parent (see the [#inherited](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Class.html#M002785) hook). Thus, when you call Amodel#find or Bmodel#find, if the subclass isn't known, it can't be found yet.

In production, this problem wouldn't be apparent, because Rails will load all models when it starts, preventing this kind of problem.

Comment: Thank you for the simple answer! Afterwards, forcing Cmodel to be loaded in initializer, Bmodel#find has been able to return Cmodel objects without any other tricks.

Comment: Because Cmodel references Bmodel, loading Cmodel forces Bmodel to load, which is why you don't need any other references.